# How to repair ruby on rails on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I have ruby on rails installed and something kinda went fubar on it.  When I try to generate a controller, I get the following:

```
➜  librius rails generate controller Teachers
Running via Spring preloader in process 27015
/Users/erick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /Users/erick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/erick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/erick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/erick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/erick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
➜  librius
```

I've tried to uninstall/reinstall using gem and RVM but nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to restart Spring? It is worth a try: `spring stop`

Comment: If you've been messing around with the source of a particular gem, then `gem pristine [gemname]` will restore it. You could also use `gem pristine --all` to reset all gems to a pristine state.

Comment: I did a gem upgrade (which I had to download because it kept telling me I had the latest). Then I did `gem pristine --all`, then `spring stop`.  (Still wasn't working.) Then lastly, `bundle install` and voila!  Such a hassle! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The comments helped point in the right direction.

I did a gem upgrade (which I had to download because it kept telling me I had the latest). Then I did `gem pristine --all`, then `spring stop`.  (Still wasn't working.) Then lastly, `bundle install` and voila!  Such a hassle! Thanks!